# Why there are two class files generated after compiling scala code?

Tags: scala

When we compile scala code using

```
scalac code.scala
```

There are two files created named `code.class` and `code$.class`.
What is the purpose of this second file?

For reference,

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main (args: Array[String]) {
        println ("Hello world! This is my first scala program!");
    }
}
```

This is the code inside `code.scala` file.

Comment: What do you have in your source file `code.scala`?

Comment: There is just one object named Code having one main def in its body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the consequence of how Scala translates the Scala `object` to JVM constructs. An `object X` is translated to a class `X$` with ordinary methods, ordinary inheritance etc.

As `object X` creates singleton in Scala, it would be nice to be able to access its public methods from Java by calling them as static methods `X.someMethod()`. That is why the Scala compiler creates also a class `X` with static methods calling the ordinary methods of the singleton instance of the class `X$`. Even if you don't have the Scala class `X` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Second file is for companion object, if you have both

```
class Code{}
object Code{}
```

in your file

Comment: But I don't have class in my file. I just have an object.